# Collapse date by year in excel column

Tags: excel, date, formatting, ms-office

I have date column in a spreadsheet created by a powershell script and I am not able to collapse the dates into months and years like this

[image: Collapsed Date]

This is the column data that I have

[image: Date Column]

I have tried going into options and selected the check mark from Group Dates in the AutoFilter menu. I've tried changing the data type to long date, custom and nothing has worked. Any ideas here as to what I might be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the column

Do the Replace hotkey (Ctrl+H in english excel, it may vary)

Find "/" (no quotes)

Replace with "/" (also no quotes)

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot. Just curious - What is the difference between the two characters though?

Comment: It seems that both the characters are the same. When I kept in excel in different cells and compared them, it returned a TRUE.

Comment: It worked because when you replaced it excel "retyped" the cell. When it retyped, it identified as date, so it converted from text to date.

Answer (score 0):

Check your formatting. Are the dates really formatted as a date or are they text. In your first screenshot you have **Sort Oldest to Newest** while in you second you have **Sort A to Z** as your sorting options.